# Reindex only a single Model from the command line in SearchKick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I am stuck trying to reindex a single model in SearchKick.

If I run the following command:

```
rails Profile.reindex
```

I get the following error:

```
Profile.reindex: command not found
```

I am able to run the command

```
rails searchkick:reindex:all
```

but that takes over an hour because of the size of my other models.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Gerard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-index just the `Profile` class using

```
rails searchkick:reindex CLASS=Profile
```

If you just run

```
rails searchkick:reindex
```

It will provide the USAGE explanation

Example buried in the [Docs](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#intelligent-search)

Explanation in the Source Code: [Searchkick rake tasks](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/master/lib/tasks/searchkick.rake#L3)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the rails console, `Profile.reindex` should work fine, provided you have set up searchkick in the model.